# Snow Leopard - Remove MobileMe / iSync menu bar icon

Tags: macos, mac, osx-snow-leopard, sync, calendar.app

Snow Leopard lets one sync his/her own Google contacts and Yahoo contacts to iCal and Address Book.  However, a side effect of this is that you will get a Sync Menu Bar item added. For some this is useful, for me its annoying and removing this menu bar item is not as intuitive as one would think. Please explain how to remove the MobileMe / iSync menu bar item?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Very easy actually

- System Preferences
- MobileMe
- Sync
- Untick Show Status in Menu Bar

[image: MobileMe Sync Preferences]

Comment: Diago, you are a gun!  It is very easy and I looked 3 separate times and my eyes just 'read' over this option!

Answer (score 20):

Command-click on the menu bar icon and drag it off to remove it.

Comment: Nice - I couldn't get to System Prefs -> MobileMe -> Sync at all as I no longer use MobileMe (there's just a login form now), but this way I got rid of the icon.

Comment: +1 I love this place ;-) I asked a question that was simple but I couldn't find; Diago answers within 20 mins (without being condescending) and the answer gets improved by Arathorn within another 10 mins.  I just wish my workplace was like this!!

Comment: @Jonik: Had the same issue, which is what caused me to try it out.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't use Mobile Me and hence don't have the option in system preferences, start iSync from the Applications folder, then you'll find "Show status in menu bar" in it's preferences.

Comment: I think this is the best method now that Mobile Me is dead.